# Hinge allowance for driveway gate

Tags: hinges, gates

I am building a driveway gate which spans about 15 feet i.e. each gate will be about 7.5 feet wide. I ordered [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08F2FN48X) hinges and would like to figure out the exact width of each gate. The "pivot" of the hinge (measurement C in the link) is 1/2 inch so does that mean I should subtract 1/2 inch from the width of each gate? And should I allow for a gap in the middle where the gates meet when closed?

thanks in advance!
Eric

Answer (score 1):

There are other issues at stake.  It is unlikely that your posts are truly straight?

So you have to

- Either allow for packing under the hinges.  Invariably this can move the top or the bottom of the gate over by a fair bit.
- Or make the gates non square (yuck)

I would suggest that

- You mount the hinges on the gate  first and square them off.  Then measure the gate size required.
- Or leave a good inch gap between the gates.

Comment: Agreed. To the OP: keep in mind that these are heavy gates, so post movement is a possibility. If you haven't already, plan on gate wheels at the middles. And I'm hoping you're doing more than 2 hinges per side.

Answer (score 0):

C does not go in the gap between the gate and the post, so just allow the usual 1/8" in that position.

allow 1/8" in the middle or more if you think the posts may move over time.